# Google Appengine One To Many and querying by collection_name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

Under the section: **One to Many** in 
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html
they show how to model these relationships.

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    # Basic info.
    name = db.StringProperty()
    birth_day = db.DateProperty()
```

...

```
class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    contact = db.ReferenceProperty(Contact,
                                   collection_name='phone_numbers')
```

...

What it seems to me is that
if you execute the following

```
scott = Contact(name='Scott')
scott.put()
PhoneNumber(contact=scott,
            phone_type='home',
            number='(650) 555 - 2200').put()
PhoneNumber(contact=scott,
            phone_type='mobile',
            number='(650) 555 - 2201').put()


 for phone in scott.phone_numbers:
     print '%s: %s' % (phone.phone_type, phone.number)

 for phone in scott.phone_numbers:
     print '%s: %s' % (phone.phone_type, phone.number)
```

The second **for** above will query the datastore again.

If for some reason you were looping over "Scott" and calling phone_numbers, it would execute lots of reads.  Is there some pattern for caching these on the first read during the lifetime of a request?  or would it need to be handled manual?

Tx.

Comment: You could cache the data in memcache when you retrieve it the first time, but you have no guarantee that the data will be there over time. If this operations you are actually intending on performing are happening in close proximity, memcache should work. Here are some docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html

Answer (score 2):

The implicit collection 'phone_numbers' is being constructed via a query, and it's tricky to cache query results.  It's difficult to determine which cached query results should be invalidated as the result of a write.

One approach could be to use ndb and its caching support ( http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/ ). ndb is now included in the SDK, since 1.6.2.

ndb doesn't cache query results, but it caches entities fetched by key, and so you could do something like this to leverage its caching (where PhoneNumber and Contact extend ndb.model.Model):

```
 phone_number = PhoneNumber(parent=contact_key, number='xxx')
 phone_number.put()
 ....
 phone_numbers = ndb.get_multi(PhoneNumber.query(ancestor=contact_key).fetch(keys_only=True))
```

See this discussion-- note the caveats re: performing queries vs key fetches inside a transaction in ndb: https://groups.google.com/group/appengine-ndb-discuss/browse_thread/thread/89dc6c019347b2a2/7f1db25d76515d07?lnk=gst&q=query+result+caching#7f1db25d76515d07